# DataTable Linq where clause to upper case comparison

Tags: c#, linq

I have a query like this.

```
 DataTable products = ...
 redirect_str = ...

 IEnumerable<DataRow> productsQuery =
                    from product in products.AsEnumerable()
                    where product.Field<String>("url") == redirect_str
                    select product;
```

it works fine.

but how can I compare product.Field("url") to redirect_str without considering case
. I tried this but it doesn't work.

```
 IEnumerable<DataRow> productsQuery =
                    from product in products.AsEnumerable()
                    where product.Field<String>("url").ToUpper() == redirect_str.ToUpper()
                    select product;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't say what you mean by "doesn't work", but you could try:

```
...
where String.Equals(product.Field<String>("url"),  
    redirect_str, 
    StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
...
```

This will work (*) even if one of the values is null, whereas your use of `ToUpper()` would throw a `NullReferenceException`.

(*) "work" if you want a culture-insensitive ordinal comparison.  If not, use a different value for the StringComparison parameter.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The error I have got is NullReferenceException. It was confused, but when you mentioned the value of null, I understand.